# Weather widget in notification center of iOS5

Tags: ipad, ios, notifications

Is there a way to put weather widget into notification center of iOS5 for iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the iPod/iPhone Weather app has never existed on the iPad, the answer to this is an extremely simple, and extremely disappointing: "Nope".